# Can a dataset built upon another have more restrictive license?

Tags: dataset, wikipedia

I found a dataset built on top of Wikipedia dump, which comes in Huggingface Dataset library. The Wikipedia dump is licensed under CC BY-SA and the Huggingface Dataset is licensed under Apache-2.0, but there is no license specified for the dataset I want to use. My question is, can the dataset be licensed under more restrictive license? Or can I assume, that it has the same license as Wikipedia dump?

Comment: This question looks like a better fit for https://law.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Even better places to ask this question would be https://opendata.stackexchange.com/ or https://opensource.stackexchange.com/. I think the latter is more specifically about licensing issues but I could be wrong.